# When the linear operator is self-adjoint?

Tags: linear-algebra

Subspaces $V_1, V_2$ of the Euclidean space $E$ such that $E = V_1 \oplus V_2$. Under what conditions on $V_1, V_2$ the projection operator on $V_1$ parallel to $V_2$ is self-adjoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the case if and only if $V_1$ and $V_2$ are orthogonal to each other. Take $v_1\in V_1$ and $v_2\in V_2$ and call the projection $p$. Then $p(v_1)=v_1$ and $p(v_2)=0$, so $\langle p(v_1),v_2\rangle=\langle v_1,p(v_2)\rangle$ implies $\langle v_1,v_2\rangle=0$. Conversely, it is well known that orthogonal projections are self-adjoint.